# Why does gcc generates strange code without flag -fno-pie?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, i386, position-independent-code

I am trying to compile dummy function in gcc with flag -fno-pie and without.

```
void dummy_test_entrypoint() { }
```

When i compile without the flag.

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c test.c -o test.o
```

I get the following disassembled code.

```
00000000 <dummy_test_entrypoint>:
0:  55                      push   ebp
1:  89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
3:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <dummy_test_entrypoint+0x4>
8:  05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
d:  90                      nop
e:  5d                      pop    ebp
f:  c3                      ret
```

When i compile with the flag.

```
00000000 <dummy_test_entrypoint>:
0:  55                      push   ebp
1:  89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
3:  90                      nop
4:  5d                      pop    ebp
5:  c3                      ret
```

My question.

What is it???

```
3:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <dummy_test_entrypoint+0x4>
8:  05 01 00 00 00          add    eax,0x1
```

Answer (score 7):

You disassembled the object file without the `--reloc` flag, so the output is misleading.  With the `--reloc` flag, you'll see this:

```
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <dummy_test_entrypoint+0x4>
            4: R_386_PC32   __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
   8:   05 01 00 00 00          add    $0x1,%eax
            9: R_386_GOTPC  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

And the subroutine looks like this:

```
00000000 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>:
   0:   8b 04 24                mov    (%esp),%eax
   3:   c3                      ret
```

This construct loads the GOT pointer into `%eax`, in case the function needs to reference global data.  The function does not contain such a reference, but because you compiled the code without optimization, GCC did not remove the dead code.