# How to understand this AT&T i386 assembly code snippet?

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, att, i386

Please view the following code snippets:

```cpp
int& sum(int& num1, int& num2) {
    num1++;
    num2++;
}
```

```
00000000 <_Z3sumRiS_>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <_Z3sumRiS_+0x4>    // why here is a jump
   8:   05 01 00 00 00          add    $0x1,%eax     

   // why 0x8, my understanding is there are in total 3 parameters
   // num2 -- 0xc(%ebp), num1 -- 0x8(%ebp), this -- 0x4(%ebp)
   // am I right????
   d:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax

  10:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  12:   8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%eax),%edx        // what the heck is this?
  15:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  18:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
  1a:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
  1d:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  1f:   8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%eax),%edx
  22:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
  25:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
  27:   90                      nop
  28:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  29:   c3                      ret
```

I need to figure out the meaning of every single line of it, kinda confused me.

Comment: That isn't a C++ member function so there's no `this` argument.  The stack slot above the saved EBP is the return address. Also, it has undefined behaviour because you fall off the end of a non-`void` function.  GCC `-O0` seems to on purpose evaluate the last expression with side effects in the return-value register, so this [sort of works as returning `num2++`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c#comment403454_106067) if you only care about `gcc -O0`.  It's totally broken for any other use.

Comment: @PeterCordes That was a C++ code. I used it as an experience. No return value on purpose.

Comment: As for `what the heck is this?`, `lea    0x1(%eax),%edx` loads the value that `eax` points to, adds one, then stores the result in `edx`. IOW, this is part of your `num1++;` - the store to memory that follows completes it.

Comment: Looking at compiler output from code with Undefined Behaviour could be confusing, I don't recommend it as the first thing you start with.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) - https://godbolt.org/ can match up source lines with asm blocks.

Comment: I know this is C++, the `&` reference makes that clear.  But it's not a *member* function so there's no `this` pointer.  If you did `auto tmp = this;` in that function, it would be a compile-time error.

Comment: yeah, this is not a member function, I just don't get why the assembly starts from `0x8(%ebx)`, rather than `0x4(%ebx)` @PeterCordes

Comment: It's using EBP as the frame pointer, not EBX.  [What are the ESP and the EBP registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773337) - `4(%ebp)` is the return address, `8(%ebp)` is the first stack arg.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If what you said was right, then what `add    $0x1,%eax` does?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think EBP is the base pointer. why is `mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax`, what's the meaning of this line. Why it use ebp to locate `0x8(%ebp)`

Comment: Did you read the rest of my last comment?  I linked you an answer that explains it.  (And I just edited my comment to say more.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Just saw it. Thx. I know how they work. My point was `add    $0x1,%eax`

Comment: Also, the `call` / `add` is because this is a 32-bit PIE, and with optimization disabled GCC is making code to get a pointer to the GOT.  And you're looking at disassembly of a `.o` so the linker hasn't filled in offsets yet.  Use `objdump -drwC` (and preferably `-Mintel` unless you actually like AT&T syntax).  Or much better, look at compiler asm output instead of disassembly from binary.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <_Z3sumRiS_+0x4>
```

This isn't the real destination of the call, it is something will be filled in by linker. If you run `objdump -dr sum.o`, you will find it is actually a call to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax`. Same for the following `add`, to set up a pointer to the GOT.  (This function doesn't need one but you compiled without optimization, with `-fpie` on by default.)

For more details, take a look [Why does gcc generates strange code without flag -fno-pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831288/why-does-gcc-generates-strange-code-without-flag-fno-pie)

---

[System V i386 ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf), Section 2.2.2 tells the structure of a stack frame.

[image: System V i386 ABI Table 2.2]

So your stack frame looks like this:

```
0xc  |      num2      |
0x8  |      num1      |
0x4  | return address |
0x0  | previous %ebp  |  <-- %ebp
```

For remaining instructions, here is a step-by-step analysis.

```
// as num1 and num2 are references, they represents address in assembly
   d:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax        // load num1 to %eax
  10:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax           // load *num1 to %eax
  12:   8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%eax),%edx        // put *num1 + 1 into %edx
  15:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax        // load num1 to %eax
  18:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)           // save *num1 + 1 at num1
  1a:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax        // same as above
  1d:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  1f:   8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%eax),%edx
  22:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
  25:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
```